# How do I create an array of Points?

Tags: javascript

How to create point object containing x,y and creating its array?
so that i can loop over those points, add/remove points dynamically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var points = [{x:45, y:64}, {x:56, y:98}, {x:23, y:44}];
var len = points.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    alert(points[i].x + ' ' + points[i].y);               
}
​
// to add more points, push an object to the array:
points.push({x:56, y:87});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gjHeV/

Answer (score 14):

You can create a constructor for a Point object like this:

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
```

Now you can create Point objects using the `new` keyword:

```
var p = new Point(4.5, 19.0);
```

To create an array of Point objects you simply create an array, and put Point objects in it:

```
var a = [ new Point(1,2), new Point(5,6), new Point(-1,14) ];
```

Or:

```
var a = [];
a.push(new Point(1,2));
a.push(new Point(5,6));
a.push(new Point(-1,14));
```

You use the `.` operator to access the properties in the Point object. Example:

```
alert(a[2].x);
```

Or:

```
var p = a[2];
alert(p.x + ',' + p.y);
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read about [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) to learn all that. It is important that you know the basics.

Example for adding:

```
var points = [];
points.push({x:5, y:3});
```

Answer (score 0):

Faster, more efficient:

```
var points = [ [45,64], [56,98], [23,44] ];
for(var i=0, len=points.length; i<len; i++){
    //put your code here
    console.log( 'x'+points[i][0], 'y'+points[i][1] )
}
// to add more points, push an array to the array:
points.push([100,100]);
```

The efficiency will only really be noticeable in a very large array of points.

Comment: I was curious whether this really was more efficient (for a particular project I was working on using [Javascript Clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) (trying to decide what internal representation to use), and according to the following JsPerf results, it would appear as though an object representation is more efficient than an array representation: https://jsperf.com/point2d-object-vs-array and https://jsperf.com/point2d-object-vs-array-property-access

Comment: This was from 8 years ago and I have no idea why I just copied the most popular answer. What is it you're trying to test?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that although you mentioned the array of 2d-arrays as being "faster, [and] more efficient," that doesn't seem to be the case (at least not in the latest version of Chrome). I'm working on a high-performance web application where we are rendering very large contour data and I came across this post while searching for which data structure would give the best performance (hence the JsPerf tests).

Comment: @Sanuden: Your links are broken.